Are there more than two numbers less than $10^4$ which are integral multiples of their "reversals"?
In Section 15 in the book A Mathematician's Apology by G. H. Hardy it says

$8712$ and $9801$ are the only four-figure numbers which are
integral multiples of their ‘reversals’: $$8712 = 4 \cdot2178,\quad 9801 = 9 \cdot1089
$$ and there are no other numbers below $10,000$ which have this
property.

This seems to be false. Given a positive integer $n$ let $r(n)$ be the "reversal" of $n$.
We have
$$r(10)=01=1\implies 10=10\cdot r(10)$$
$$r(5885)=5885\implies 5885=1\cdot r(5885)$$
$$r(60)=06=6\implies 60=10\cdot r(60),$$ and there are many more examples.
Are the above examples in some sense "trivial," and therefore Hardy didn't include them?

Any palindrome number would be an example if $r(n)=1\cdot n$ were permitted, so I'd be inclined to at least specify that the integer multiple be larger than $1$.

The quote appears to require $4$ digits and, at a guess, excludes palindromes.

See also OEIS sequence A008919, where there's also a specification that the reversal is a "nontrivial" multiple of the original. Mathworld's entry on reversals includes the following as well: "Ball and Coxeter (1987) consider numbers whose reversals are integral multiples of themselves. Palindromic numbers and numbers ending with a zero are trivial examples."
